# Any idea What is this? - marked words with 2 colors

Tags: visual-studio-code

Use Arch Linux,

I don't know what is due,

Any idea where to look for.

Visual Code assigns double color to the same word

[image: img]

I'm still looking within the configurations that create this problem

Comment: That is definitely odd looking. If I had to guess it is that VS isn't recognizing, or is mis-recognizing the code file in question. So it isn't recognizing the quoted text as a string and is instead picking up on some form of keyword.  Are you using a standard file extension for the language you are working with?

Comment: use the TextMate Scope inspector to see why the stuff is white

Comment: Looks like a bug in the syntax highlighter. What language are you using, and what syntax highlighter? You might want to file a bug report.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers, This appears in Java and JS projects, This is from a Java project. Textmate shows me this
The string that has 2 colors is selected
https://i.ibb.co/WBwdsSH/textmate-vscode-color-text.png

Comment: In the extensions search engine I put syntax highlight and nothing appears
https://i.ibb.co/dPFjpgj/search-syntax-highlighter.png

config syntax highlighter https://i.ibb.co/KykrLPK/config-syntax-highlighter.png

installed extensions https://textdoc.co/fsgB38LkIEpaJRrq